# V-client-table filterbycolumn how do I get the filter to work for some but not all columns?

Tags: javascript, laravel

this is a question about vue and its v-table, specifically its v-client-table

This example has a filter on name pets and birthdays but not on age, edit or delete.  https://jsfiddle.net/f5h8xwgn/299/

I need something similar but I'm unable to reproduce the affect in my project.  I have 3 columns: name, active, and edit - edit is just a bunch of buttons - I don't need to sort or filter buttons.

this is my code code for the table:

```
<v-client-table :data="filteredList"
    :columns="['name', 'active', 'edit']" :options="options"
    >
    <template slot="name" scope="props">
        <div v-if="props.row.editing">
            <textbox v-model="editName"></textbox>
        </div>
        <div v-else>{{ props.row.name }}</div>    
    </template>

    <template slot="active" scope="props">
        <div v-if="props.row.editing">                            
            <select class="form-control" v-model="editActive">
                <option v-bind:value="1">Active</option>
                <option v-bind:value="0">Inactive</option>
            </select>                            
        </div>

        <div v-else>
            <div v-if="props.row.active">Active</div>
            <div v-else>Inactive</div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template slot="edit" scope="props">
        <div class="text-right">                        
            <button type = "button" 
                 @click="editFabricator(props.row)" 
                 class="btn btn-primary">
                <div v-if="props.row.editing">Cancel</div>
                <div v-else>Edit</div>
            </button> 
            <button v-if="props.row.editing" 
                type = "button" 
                @click="saveEdit(props.row.id)" class="btn btn-primary">
                Save
            </button>
        </div> 
    </template>


</v-client-table>
```

this is my options

```
options: {
    filterByColumn: true,
    headers: {
        name: 'Name',
        active: 'Active',
        edit: 'Edit',
    },
    listColumns: {
        active: [{
          id: '0',
          text: 'Inactive'
        }, {
          id: '1',
          text: 'Active'
        }]
      },
}
```

in the example on jsfiddle edit isn't listed in the :columns list when the table is declared but it still shows up in the table.  if I remove edit from the :columns list it removes the edit column from the table and no matter what I do I can't get it to show up.  if I put edit in the :columns list then the column is there but it has a filter. which I don't want.

this is for a laravel project. not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Under Options add the columns you want to filter by using the
filterable option.

```
{
    "options": {
        "filterByColumn": true,
        "filterable": [
            "name",
            "active"
        ],
        "headers": {
            "name": "Name",
            "active": "Active",
            "edit": "Edit"
        },
        "listColumns": {
            "active": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "text": "Inactive"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "text": "Active"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/options-api